# Laravel 5 how to return a template with response()->json()?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, laravel-5.1

Below is my database:

```
post:
id user_name content created_at
```

Below is my post controller:

```
public function new(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $post = new Post;
        $post->user_name = $data['name'];
        $post->message = $data['content'];
        $post->save();
        $id = $post->id;
        $show = Post::find($id)->first();
        // $html = view('wall.post')->with('post', $show);
        return response()->json(['success' => $post->id,'message'=> 'Post Sent', 'html' => $html]);
    }
```

and my /views/wall/post.blade.php :

```
<div class="ui post">
<div class="name">User : {{ $post->user_name }}</div>
<div class="content">{{ $post->content }}</div>
</div>
```

Below is my question:

> how do i get the content from **post.blade.php** with *user_name* and
>   *content* return as below to **$html** in **new()** when i post name=kenny and content=testing:

```
<div class="ui post">
<div class="name">User : Kenny</div>
<div class="content">Testing</div>
</div>
```

and i just use jquery to prepend above code to my page?

Thanks

{Sorry if i got bad grammar in my english}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a view like this:

```
<?php
$html = view('wall/post')->render();
```

Comment: Thanks @Joachim Martinsen
i use as below and it work.
`$data = Post::where('id',$id)->first();
 $html = view('wall.post')->with('post', $data)->render();`